# how to find upper limit of integral if area is known in R?

Tags: r

user, 
I am not so familiar with mathematics nor R, but I have a probability question, with a continues probability density. I should find the time where it is 50 % probable that a battery will fail. I believe that this can be expressed as setting the area of the probability density to 0.5 (50%), and it would be very cool if it was possible to say something like this in R; 
f = probability density function
0.5 = exp(f, lower = 0, upper = x), and R would calculate x.

Is there some easy way to calculate the range of the integral given a lower limit and the area in R?

Comment: What you describe is called a quantile. For common distributions quantile functions are available in R, e.g. `qnorm` for the normal distribution.

Comment: but its no way of giving a random function (that is a distribution) for instance a normal distribution where I am unaware know that it is a normal distribution?

Comment: Trying to do statistics without some background knowledge in statistics is dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty inefficient, but you it allows you to use an arbitrary density function

```
findprob <- function(f, interval, target) {
    optimize(function(x) {
        abs(integrate(f, -Inf, x)$value-target)
    }, interval)$minimum
}

mydensity <- function(x) dnorm(x)
findprob(mydensity, interval=c(-1,1), target=.5)
```

Here we use `optimize` to find a value for the integral where the distance from our target value is minimized. Note that `optimize` needs an interval in which to search for a solution so you'll want to have some idea of where the point might occur.

Comment: mrFlick. I was thinking about this too, but was hoping for a inbuilt function call.